# Two post in one file

Tags: php, html

In my code i have two buttons each performing different tasks. These two buttons are put into two posts but my code accept only one post. How could i put two post in the same file for the file to run successfully. Any Help.? Below is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['search']))
  { 
     $txtStartDate=$_POST['txtStartDate'];
     $txtEndDate=$_POST['txtEndDate'];
     $productResult = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT 
               invoiceissued.date_created as Date,
               outlets.outletname as OutletName,
               outlets.barcode as Barcode,
               invoiceissued.invoiceno as InvoiceNo, 
               outlets.businessregistrationno as BRNno,
               outlets.vat as VAT,
               invoiceissued.VATAmount as VATAmount, 
                invoiceissued.total_amount as TotalAmount, 
                invoiceissued.total_amount - invoiceissued.VATAmount 
             FROM `invoiceissued` , outlets
             WHERE invoiceissued.outletid = outlets.outletsid
             and `date_created` BETWEEN '$txtStartDate' AND '$txtEndDate'");
  }
  if(isset($_POST['export']))
  {
      $filename = "Export_excel.txt";
      header("Content-Type: text/plain");
      header("Content-Disposition: attachment; 
      filename=\"$filename\"");
      $isPrintHeader = false;
      if (! empty($productResult)) 
      {
            foreach ($productResult as $row) {
            if (! $isPrintHeader) {
            echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\n";
            $isPrintHeader = true;
            }
           echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\n";
           }
          }
          exit();


     }
```

Comment: what you want ?? at a time only one POST method will call even if you put in same file.
or you can check which method is called using var_dump($_POST) or print_r($_POST).

Comment: If the POST request contains both fields (search and export) - then your 2 code branches will both execute.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(isset($_POST['search']) || isset($_POST['export']))
  {
  if(isset($_POST['search']))
  { 
     $txtStartDate=$_POST['txtStartDate'];
     $txtEndDate=$_POST['txtEndDate'];
     $productResult = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT 
               invoiceissued.date_created as Date,
               outlets.outletname as OutletName,
               outlets.barcode as Barcode,
               invoiceissued.invoiceno as InvoiceNo, 
               outlets.businessregistrationno as BRNno,
               outlets.vat as VAT,
               invoiceissued.VATAmount as VATAmount, 
                invoiceissued.total_amount as TotalAmount, 
                invoiceissued.total_amount - invoiceissued.VATAmount 
             FROM `invoiceissued` , outlets
             WHERE invoiceissued.outletid = outlets.outletsid
             and `date_created` BETWEEN '$txtStartDate' AND '$txtEndDate'");
  }
  if(isset($_POST['export']))
  {
      $filename = "Export_excel.txt";
      header("Content-Type: text/plain");
      header("Content-Disposition: attachment; 
      filename=\"$filename\"");
      $isPrintHeader = false;
      if (! empty($productResult)) 
      {
            foreach ($productResult as $row) {
            if (! $isPrintHeader) {
            echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\n";
            $isPrintHeader = true;
            }
           echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\n";
           }
          }
          exit();
     }
  }
```

You can write this. If the POST request contains both fields (search and export) OR else one method will be called.